# Получить атрибут объекта по его имени

Tags: python, классы

Пожалуйста, подскажите как это сделать правильно?

```
sel_list = ['Период', 'Доход']

query = connects.V83.NewObject("Query", query)  # Выполняем запрос к базе 1С
sel = query.Execute().Choose()
while sel.next():
      print(sel.Период) # Рабочий вариант но не подходит
      print(sel.Доход)  # Так как вручную указывать не вариант
      print(sel.sel_list[0] # Нужен примерно такой вариант
      print(sel.sel_list[1]
```

Я понимаю, что пытаюсь к объекту дописать строку но мне это очень нужно. Как это правильно сделать??

Comment: stroka='print(sel.{})'.format(sel_list[0])
eval(stroka) делаем форматированую строку и запускаем eval

Comment: Щас проверю, отпишусь

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ох уж эти советчики. Не слушайте тех, кто советует использовать eval в ситуации, когда есть нормальное решение.

```
print(getattr(sel, sel_list[0]))
```

Comment: Работает на ура, спасибо сенсей